# What's the most practical clothing for a weretiger or other were animal?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, equipment, lycanthropy

Werewolves, and other similar shapechangers, are usually significantly larger in an animal or hybrid form than in their human form, so wearing clothes when they shift is a very bad idea. For this reason, it would make sense that there is a certain style of clothing that is preferred by them on a kind of cultural level.

There are exceptions to this observation, but the majority of were animals would want to wear certain clothes while in their human form that would be easiest to remove before a shift, or else risk the pain of tearing through them on top of the pain of the shift itself.

What is the ideal outfit, or outfits, for a were animal in a high fantasy setting, specifically, for a weretiger, or a werebear?

Answer (score 6):

In DnD 3.5, Lycanthropes have the [Alternate Form](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#alternateForm) supernatural ability. Alternate form includes the following line:

> Any gear worn or carried by the creature that can’t be worn or carried
>   in its new form instead falls to the ground in its space. If the
>   creature changes size, any gear it wears or carries that can be worn
>   or carried in its new form changes size to match the new size.
>   (Nonhumanoid-shaped creatures can’t wear armor designed for
>   humanoid-shaped creatures, and vice versa.) Gear returns to normal
>   size if dropped.

So, despite what might seem intuitive, wearing clothes is actually completely fine for werewolves. If if they switch to hybrid form, their clothes change size to fit them. If they change to wolf form, their clothes fall on the ground unharmed.

Despite this, two lycanthropes do have specific clothing preferences:

- A wereboar "dresses in simple garments that are easy to remove,
  repair, or replace."
- Werebears "dress in simple cloth and leather
  garments that are easy to remove, repair, or replace."

(both from [here](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/lycanthrope.htm))

Answer (score 1):

### Clothing? No problems...

As mentioned on p213 of the DMG (the 2013 edition...):

> When an article of magic clothing or jewelry is discovered, most of the time size shouldn’t be an issue. Many magic garments are made to be easily adjustable, or they adjust themselves magically to the wearer. As a rule, size should not keep overweight characters, characters of various genders, or characters of various kinds from using magic items. Players shouldn’t be penalized for choosing a halfling character or deciding that their character is especially tall.
>
> Only say "It doesn’t fit" if there’s a good reason. Cloaks made specifically by the selfish, self-absorbed drow elves might fit only elves. Dwarves might make items usable only by dwarf-sized and dwarf-shaped characters to keep their items from being used against them. Such items should be the exceptions, however, not the rule.

So, magic clothing (including magic cloaks, interestingly) and magic jewelry should auto-resize. Weapons and armor, do not.

However, you could gimmick the system somewhat if you add armor bonuses to items of clothing (such as certain magic robes), should your DM allow it. If you do this, don't come back to me when your DM books you in the head when you try to save on crafting costs by sizing them for very tiny creatures. Try that and I can see hordes of tiny angry fey along with the local Cobbler's Union 517 after your tail.

---

Be aware that Wild Shape (and similarly based abilities) may override this due to the absorption clause. You'll have to find out from your DM in advance whether magic clothing wins vs wildshaping or similar... otherwise you may be joining a certain emperor....

Also note that there is a sizing enhancement available for weapons.